# Groovy: What Does "?" Mean in This Context?

Tags: groovy, syntax

I am new to Groovy and am having trouble understanding the function of this code.

```
def aList
def foo = aList.size() == 1 ? aList[0] : null
```

Trying to break it down, I think

- `aList.size() == 1 ?` is asserting that the size of the list is 1 and not null.
- `aList[0] : null` means that the value at `aList[0]` defaults to null

Therefore `foo` is the value of the first item in the list, and defaults to null.

Is this correct, or am I misunderstanding how this is meant to be behaving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [ternary conditional operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator)

it takes the form:

```
SOME_BOOLEAN ? IF_TRUE : ELSE
```

So in your case, it's the same as:

```
def foo = null
if(aList.size() == 1) {
    foo = aList[0]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation, I think I understand this now. Thanks for the link as well, I was struggling to find meaningful results through searching to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

its a one line if statement. expanded this would look like this :

```
if( aList.size() == 1) {
   foo = aList[0];
 }
else {
foo = null;
}
```

Hope that clears it up.